# How can I replace / edit only a specific word in Java?

Tags: java, string, replace

I want a specific word being replaced/ edited. But unfortunately, other words are replaced too who contain the word to be replaced.

Example:

**String test = "I am a ool tool";**

Now if I want to replace the word "ool" with something, "tool" is gonna be changed as well. So how can I solve this problem? I JUST want ool to be edited. "tool" should stay like it is.

Here some code:

```
public class StringMethoden {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    String bsp = "I am a ool tool";

    if (bsp.matches("(.*)ool(.*)")){


        bsp = bsp.replaceAll("ool", "test");
        System.out.println(bsp);
             }
    else {
        System.out.println("sentence does not conain 'ool' !");
    }}
```

> Outut: I am a test ttest

Comment: What's the difference between the word `"ool"` and a partial word `"*ool*"`? The complete word is not surrounded by other letters.

Answer (score 2):

Word boundaries (`\b`) in Java RegEx make sure a certain point in the string is the start/end of a word.

```
bsp = bsp.replaceAll("\\bool\\b", "test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar approach for the issue, we can also use **.contains()** method in the following manner, feel free to ask questions if any.

```
    String bsp = "I am a ool tool";
    if (bsp.contains(" ool")) {

        bsp = bsp.replaceAll(" ool", " test");
        System.out.println(bsp);
    } else {
        System.out.println("sentence does not conain 'ool' !");
    }
```

Output:

> I am a test tool